# Excel count rows between 2 strings

Tags: excel, vba

I need to place row headers in column A. This will vary from each page so I need a VBA to handle this. I need to count the number of rows between two cell and then serielize the headers.

[image]

To

[image]

So I need too

1. Loop thrugh Column B
2. sCell = Find what cell is in
3. Samples = count cells in between s and Inspector
4. StartCell = sCell + 1
5. Loop StartCell to Samples

Is this correct?

Comment: Will you only be adding headers in cells next to numbers? Or does that happen to be a coincidence?  Also, as you go past row 13, will it repeat "X R s" then numbers then "Inspector" again?

Comment: I have no clue why you need vba for this...

Comment: @user3578951 - Yes only next to numbers, and no they will not repeate

Comment: @TomRuh, I don't think you'd need VBA then.  Just put this in cell A2 and drag down, does it work?  `=IF(ISNUMBER(B2),IF(A1="","1",A1+1),"")`.  Or, do you have numbers further down the page as well, and will need "8", "9", "10", etc.

Edit: you could also use this formula, `=IF(ISNUMBER(B4),ROW(B4)-MATCH("s",$B$1:$B$13,0),"")` which may be a little better, as you can put it in A1. B1:B13 is the range of the column, so if you keep going past row 13, just edit that part.

Comment: I could do it withou VBA, exept I need to do it in VBA

Answer (score 0):

#### Non-VBA Solution

(Personally I feel VBA is unnecessary)

You can use this formula starting in `A1` and autofill down:

```
=IFERROR(IF(AND(MATCH("S",B:B,0)<MATCH(B1,B:B,0),MATCH("Inspector",B:B,0)>MATCH(B1,B:B,0)),IFERROR(OFFSET(INDIRECT(CHAR(COLUMN()+64)&ROW()),-1,0)+1,1),""),"")
```

A few notes:

1. This will work for numbers and text
2. This does not work for blanks
3. If the value you are searching for is **not** unique, there might be unexpected results

Now I hardcoded "S" and "Inspector" in this, but you can of course change that to be a cell reference.  Lets say `D1` and `E1` (just remember to use absolute references `$D$1` and `$E$1`:

```
=IFERROR(IF(AND(MATCH($D$1,B:B,0)<MATCH(B1,B:B,0),MATCH($E$1,B:B,0)>MATCH(B1,B:B,0)),IFERROR(OFFSET(INDIRECT(CHAR(COLUMN()+64)&ROW()),-1,0)+1,1),""),"")
```

Answer (score 0):

Was able to do this without a loop

```
Option Explicit

Sub MarkSamples()
    Dim FoundsCell As Range
    Dim FoundeCell As Range
    Dim cStart As String
    Dim cEnd As String
    Dim EndCell As String
    Dim sampCol As String
    Dim StartCell As String
    cStart = "s" & " " & "*"
    cEnd = " Inspector"

    Set FoundsCell = Sheets("Sheet1").Columns(2).Find(cStart, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)

    Set FoundeCell = Sheets("Sheet1").Columns(2).Find(cEnd, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)

    StartCell = FoundsCell.row + 1
    EndCell = FoundeCell.row - FoundsCell.row - 1

    sampCol = "A" & StartCell
    Range(sampCol) = 1
    Range(sampCol).Select
    Selection.DataSeries Rowcol:=xlColumns, Type:=xlLinear, Date:=xlDay, _
        Step:=1, Stop:=EndCell, Trend:=False


End Sub
```